# How to fill tableview with two arrays using single custom cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to display two array values in tableview using single cell.
Suppose i have two array and both contains same no of elements.

FirstArray and SecondArray. there is two label in tableview cell *Lbl1* and *Lbl2*, now *Lbl1* should fill with **FirstArray** and *Lbl2* Should fill with **SecondArray**. I know that we can not use two array for uitableview datasource . I can not figure out how to do this.

Please help me.

I also tried using multiple custom tableview cells with section. but it did not give the desired result.

I have two Array -

```
let datalist1 = ["firstCell1" , "firstCell2" , "firstCell3" , "firstCell4"]
    let datalist2 = ["secondCell1"  ,"secondCell2" , "secondCell3" ,"secondCell4"]
```

In tableview numberOfRowsInSection :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0
        {
            return datalist1.count
        }
        else  {
            return datalist2.count
        }
    }
```

In cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? FirstCell
            cell?.initData(name: datalist1[indexPath.row])
            return cell!
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? SecondCell
            cell?.initData(lbl: datalist2[indexPath.row])
            return cell!
        }

    }
```

**Actual Output :**

FirstCell1
FirstCell2
FirstCell3
FirstCell4
SecondCell1
SecondCell2
SecondCell3
SecondCell4

**Expected Output:**

FirstCell1
SecondCell1
FirstCell2
SecondCell2
FirstCell3
SecondCell3
FirstCell4
SecondCell4

Comment: It seems like you have two kinds of cells - `FirstCell` and `SecondCell`. But in your question, you seem to imply you have one kind of cell, and that kind of cell have 2 labels?

Comment: For your expected output you need to make 2 changes. 

1. Keep single section and double the numberOfRowsInSection

2. In cellForRowAt if `indexPath.row % 2 == 0` then init with datalist1 else init with datalist2. That's it.

Comment: yes i want this in single cell only but to get expected output i tried with two cells.@Sweeper

Comment: I Tried The Way @Pavan suggest but now it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You not need to add two `section` just do as bellow.
This is your arrays.

```
let datalist1 = ["firstCell1" , "firstCell2" , "firstCell3" , "firstCell4"]
let datalist2 = ["secondCell1"  ,"secondCell2" , "secondCell3" ,"secondCell4"]
```

Number of rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return datalist1.coun
}
```

Cell for row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? FirstCell
    cell.Lbl1.text = datalist1[indexPath.row]
    cell.Lbl2.text = datalist2[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Make sure both arrays are equal objects counts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanation and code, you have provided, the requirement is not clear.
However, there may be two cases based on the above details:

**Case-1:**

Cell-1 :  FirstCell1

Cell-2 :  SecondCell1

Cell-3 :  FirstCell2

Cell-4 :  SecondCell2

Then you can implement something like below:

In tableview numberOfRowsInSection :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (datalist1.count + datalist2.count)
}
```

In cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? FirstCell
        cell?.initData(name: datalist1[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? SecondCell
        cell?.initData(lbl: datalist2[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }

}
```

**Case-2:**

Cell-1 :  FirstCell1 SecondCell1

Cell-2 :  FirstCell2 SecondCell2

Cell-3 :  FirstCell3 SecondCell3

Cell-4 :  FirstCell4 SecondCell4

Then you can implement something like below:

In tableview numberOfRowsInSection :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return datalist1.count
}
```

In cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? FirstCell
        //Single custom cell can implement both the labels
        cell?.initData(name: datalist1[indexPath.row],lbl: datalist2[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to Declare as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section %2 == 0 {
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? FirstCell
            cell1.lbl1.text = datalist1[indexPath.row]
            return cell1!
        }
        else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? SecondCell            
            cell2.lbl2.text = datalist2[indexPath.row]
            return cell2!
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using models. You have to declare data model such as

```
struct MyModel {
   var firstValue: String?
   var secondValue: String?
}
```

Then you have to convert your two arrays to a single array of MyModel objects

```
var myData = Array<MyModel>()
```

Then by using for loop you can iterate over one array and fill the myData array.

```
for (index, _) in datalist1 {
   let object = MyModel()
   object.firstValue = datalist1[index]
   object.firstValue = datalist2[index]
   myData.append(object)
}
```

Then just implement tableview protocol methods and fill your custom cell with MyModel objects.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a *single `array`* from `datalist1` and `datalist2` using `zip(_:_:)`, that we'll be using as `dataSource` for `tableView`.

```
lazy var dataList = Array(zip(self.datalist1, self.datalist2))
```

`dataList` is of type `[(String, String)]`.

**Example:**

If `datalist1` and `datalist2` are,

```
let datalist1 = ["firstCell1" , "firstCell2" , "firstCell3" , "firstCell4"]
let datalist2 = ["secondCell1"  ,"secondCell2" , "secondCell3" ,"secondCell4"]
```

then, `dataList` contains

```
[("firstCell1", "secondCell1"), ("firstCell2", "secondCell2"), ("firstCell3", "secondCell3"), ("firstCell4", "secondCell4")]
```

**2.** You need a single `cell` to display all that data. There is no need to create 2 different `UITableViewCells` for this. Example:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
}
```

**3.** Now, your `UITableViewDataSource` methods look like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.lbl1.text = self.dataList[indexPath.row].0
    cell.lbl2.text = self.dataList[indexPath.row].1
    return cell
}
```